# Access the most recent file in (alphabetically sorted) directory

Tags: shell, command-line, files, wildcards, timestamps

I'm trying to open a file with vim from the command line, the file is in a directory filled with automatically generated files that are prepended with a time stamp.  Since I don't know the time stamps off the top of my head, I would just like to open the most recent one in the directory (also the last one in the list alphabetically).

```
vim ./my_dir/<last_item>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: suggest to use append  time stamps at the end of files, that would make sorting easier, I suppose. It makes to read the filenames as well. Is the timestamp in string formatted or epoch, however?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is really a job for zsh.

```
vim my_dir/*(om[1])
```

The bits in parentheses are [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers). The `*` before is a regular glob pattern, for example if you wanted to consider only log files you could use `*.log`. The `o` glob qualifier changes the order in which the matches are sorted; `om` means sort by modification time, most recent first. The `[` glob qualifier means to only return some of the matches: `[1]` returns the first match, `[2,4]` return the next three, `[-2,-1]` return the last two and so on. If the files have names that begin with their timestamp, `*([1])` will suffice.

In other shells, there's no good way to pick the most recent file. If your file names don't contain unprintable characters or newlines, you can use

```
vim "$(ls -t mydir | head -n 1)"
```

If you want to pick the first or last file based on the name, there is a fully reliable and portable method, which is a bit verbose for the command line but perfectly serviceable in scripts.

```
set -- mydir/*
first_file_name=$1
eval "last_file_name=\${$#}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are inside my_dir:

```
vim $(ls -rt | tail -1)
```

Comment: Better to reverse the sorting and add quotes: `vim "$(ls -t | head -1)"`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$ ls -rt | tail -1 | xargs vim
```

But you may have a directory as the last entry, in which case you might want to filter directories:

```
$ ls -rt | grep -v "^d" | tail -1 | xargs vim
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this.

```
[centos@centos temp]$ for i in `seq 100`; do touch $i; done

[centos@centos temp]$ ls -t1 | head -1
100


[centos@centos temp]$ vim /.my_dir/$(ls -t1  | head -1)
```

But sorting depends entirely on your filename.