# How to open the n most recently modified files in less/vim?

Tags: files, find, ls, filenames

How can I open all and only the n (e.g. 5) most recently modified files in a directory in `less` or `vim`?

I know I can use `ls -t` to sort the output from most recent to oldest. So my intuition would be to use `ls -t | head -5 | vim` but that doesn't work since `ls` output is treadted by vim as raw text not filenames.

How do I do this with `find`? My problem with `find` is that I always use `ls` to browser directories, so know how to use it - but `find` I never use for that purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really want the shell to select those filenames, in case any of the filenames contain characters from `$IFS`, usually space, tab, or newlines. You can work around this by asking (GNU) `find` utility to find the files and separate their filenames with NULLs then using the (GNU) `xargs` utility to separate those filenames back into less or vim, but I think it's simpler to just use a shell that can generate the filenames natively:

```
zsh -c 'vim *(om[1,5])'
```

This invokes `zsh` with a single `vim` command with a wildcard that expands to the five most recently modified files in the current directory. Those filenames are safely provided as separate arguments to `vim` -- they aren't further split by `$IFS`.

See more examples at: [Find latest files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/240418/117549), [Is it possible to reference the most recently modified file in a command line argument?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34736/117549), and [Access the most recent file in (alphabetically sorted) directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26437/117549)

Comment: Thanks! I found the explanation for what this `*(om[1,5])` construct does in a referenced answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26495/377222 So even if I use fish, there's no harm in using `zsh` just for this one command, right?

Comment: Right! That's why I demonstrated it with the `zsh -c ...` format.

Comment: Thanks, I can see that now, but when I first saw `zsh` my intuition was: _oh no, I use fish, what now?_